# Unable to find list of files in a directory and then add it to PYTHONPATH dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, dockerfile

I am trying to list-down all python zipped dependencies present in a package named "ANOTHER_PACKAGE" and then add it to PYTHONPATH.

Part of my DockerFile:

```
RUN mkdir work_dir
WORKDIR work_dir
RUN mkdir "ANOTHER_PACKAGE"
# This copies everything from my local Docker
COPY ANOTHER_PACKAGE/* ./ANOTHER_PACKAGE/

RUN CUSTOM_PATH=$(find /work_dir/ANOTHER_PACKAGE -type f | tr "\n" ":")
ENV PYTHONPATH "$CUSTOM_PATH"
RUN python3 -c "import my_custom_dependency"
```

This fails for me as when I checked sys.path I find CUSTOM_PATH was empty.
It works when manually add path to PYTHONPATH. I am suspecting something wrong with my find command, but I checked running find command manually, and it worked.

Comment: are you sure your `work_dir` in at the root of the FS?

Comment: Also you don't need to `mkdir` before `WORKDIR`. If the `WORKDIR` doesn’t exist, it will be created.

Comment: Also you don't need `/*` in the src for the COPY command, and it seems your ENV command is missing the end, probably needs to end with `H"`

Comment: even if the ENV had the last couple of characters, I don't think it would be able to pick up the result of executing a RUN command from the previous line. RUN happens in the container environment layer, ENV - is a build directive.

Comment: Another thing that came to my mind is that PYTHONPATH is a list of additional `folders`, not files, while you are listing with `-type f`. Should it be `-type d` instead?

Comment: Fixed the typo. type f because ANOTHER_PACKAGE has all dependencies zipped. Refering direct ANOTHER_PACKAGE does not detect the dependencies even if it is added manually.
Interesting to know about RUN vs ENV command difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best bet is to have an entrypoint script that will update the PYTHONPATH at the time of execution, here is how I tried:

```
> tree

.
├── Dockerfile
├── FOLD1
│   ├── FOLD2
│   │   └── a_module.py
│   └── FOLD3
│       └── b_module.py
└── entrypoint.sh
```

```
> cat Dockerfile

FROM alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY entrypoint.sh .
COPY FOLD1 ./custom_package

ENTRYPOINT /app/entrypoint.sh
```

```
> cat FOLD1/FOLD2/a_module.py

def func1():
    print("func 1 at your service")
```

```
> cat FOLD1/FOLD3/b_module.py

def func2():
    print("func 2 at your service")
```

Here is where I set the PYTHONPATH:

```
> cat entrypoint.sh

echo "installing python3"
apk add python3 > /dev/null
echo "python installed"

echo "adding custom python path"
export PYTHONPATH=$(find /app/* -type d | tr "\n" ":" | sed 's/:*$//')
echo "python path added"

echo "testing import\n"
python3 -c "import a_module, b_module; a_module.func1(); b_module.func2()"
echo "done"

sleep 1
```

finally I build the image:

```
> docker build -t test .
```

and execute:

```
> docker run -it --rm test

installing python3
python installed
adding custom python path
python path added
testing import\n
func 1 at your service
func 2 at your service
done
```

As you can see PYTHONPATH was updated and I was able to import and use a_module and b_module.